# MDX left-join of two sets

Tags: mdx, ssrs-2012

I've developed data into to sets.

The first set looks like this:

```
set1
acctA   CatA    budget  10
acctA   CatB    budget  20
acctA   CatC    budget  30
acctB   CatA    budget  10
acctB   CatB    budget  20
acctB   CatC    budget  30
acctC   CatA    budget  10
acctC   CatB    budget  20
acctC   CatC    budget  30
```

and the second set:

```
set2
acctA   CatA    expense 7
acctA   CatB    expense 8
acctB   CatB    expense 20
acctC   CatB    expense 19
acctC   CatC    expense 3
```

The output report needs to be matched up like this.

```
desired output
        CatA            CatB            CatC    
        budget  expense budget  expense budget  expense
acctA   10      7       10      8       10      -
acctB   20      -       20      23      20      -
acctC   30      -       30      19      30      3
```

In all accts there will be a budget amount in all Cat(s).
Each budget Cat will be represented in all accts just on time.

An acct will not always have an expense for a given Cat.
Any expense value has to be given to a distinct acct-Cat pair.

Would you rather return these sets to SSRS and join them in the report?
How would you join them in MDX?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know much about your cube.

To return what you mention in straight mdx is something along these lines:

```
SELECT
  [Category].[Category].MEMBERS
  *
  {[Measures].budget, [Measures].expenses} ON COLUMNS
  [Account].[Account].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [YourCube];
```

Can you amend the above please so we have an idea of your mdx?  - it will need to amended to work with SSRS as only the Measures hierarchy will be allowed on columns.

Answer (score 0):

Lol.  The correct answer is ... get those nulls our of your cube's data